# How to create webjars from my css and js file?

Tags: javascript, css, webjars

I read some articles about the webjars but I didn't really understand the purpose of use,and if I want to use webjars in a spring mvc project for example that means I have to replace my static js,css ..files with webjars and add a resource configuration in my xml configuration file but stay confused not understand the benefits of use webjar and how I can convert my css and js files to a webjars ,Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Step by step guide on how to create a webjar for Front-End Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164938/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-create-a-webjar-for-front-end-application)

Answer (score 1):

WebJars are only useful if you are using external JS / CSS libraries.  With WebJars you can specify those libraries as dependencies in your package manager (i.e. Maven) instead of putting the sources in your SCM.